# How do I write a MATLAB code that edits another MATLAB file (.m)?

Tags: matlab, file, text-manipulation

I have two files, Editor.m and Parameters.m. I want to write a code in Editor.m that when run does the following task:

- reads Parameters.m
- searches for a line in it (e.g. dt=1)
- replaces it with something else (e.g. dt=0.6)
- saves Parameters.m.

So, at the end of this process, Parameters.m will contain the line dt=0.6 instead of dt=1, without me having edited it directly.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexprep` to replace the value of interest.

```
% Read the file contents
fid = fopen('Parameters.m', 'r');
contents = fread(fid, '*char').';
fclose(fid);

% Replace the necessary values
contents = regexprep(contents, '(?<=dt=)\d*\.?\d+', '0.6');

% Save the new string back to the file
fid = fopen('Parameters.m', 'w');
fwrite(fid, contents)
fclose(fid)
```

If you can guarantee that it will only ever appear as `'dt=1'`, then you can use `strrep` instead

```
contents = strrep(contents, 'dt=1', 'dt=0.6');
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain briefly what (contents, '(?<=\ndt=).*?(?<=\n)', '0.6') means?

If I know for sure that dt=1 in my file (and it appears nowhere else in my file), can I replace it with (contents, 'dt=1', 'dt=0.6')?

Comment: @odnerpmocon It's a regular expression which matches any number that follows `dt=` and replaces it with `0.6`. It's more robust than searching for purely `dt=1`